# What is the etymology of “Narr”?

Tags: etymology

What is the etymology of Narr? Duden says it is unclear. Could  it be related to the Hebrew נער (na'ár) boy, youth via Yiddish?

Answer (score 7):

Possibly, but very unlikely.

Even if the ethymology of *Narr* is unclear, there are several (unproven) theories, Hebrew is none of them:

- Possibly from Latin *nario* (to argue, to mock so.) or french *narguer*  (to sneer)
- Possibly same root as the German *Narbe* (scar), meaning "crippled"
- Possibly same root as German *nörgeln* (grumble)

Comment: [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GN02652#XGN02652) also adds the nice (disputed) meaning of *Nasenrümpfer* ('turning up one's nose').

Comment: @guidot That's the Latin *nario*.

Comment: Magst Du  vielleicht noch dazu schreiben, woher diese Theorien stammen?

Answer (score 6):

This is an interesting suggestion. The problem is that the word exists already in Old High German (narro) in the 8th century. This is too early for a borrowing from Yiddish.

Answer (score 2):

According to Max Weinreich (History of the Yiddish Language 2, pg. 667) the word nar (נאַר‎) comes from the Germanic [*narre*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/narre), meaning "to fool" or "to trick."

The association of נאַר‎ with the Semitic נַעַר (naʕar [though in mideval Europe, nar], meaning "young man") is a false etymology, but is widespread, especially due to the Semitic plural נאַראָנים‎ (naronim, and not the expected naronen, nars, etc.) In fact, in older literature the plural was often written as if it were a Semitic נערנים (ibid, in a note to page 621). There is also a humourous saying that "every Samuel is a fool" based on 1 Samuel 2:16, beginning with "...וְהַנַּעַר שְׁמוּאֵל" (and the youth Samuel...).

Comment: But that leaves us with the question where the verb originates from.

Comment: @rha which verb? The noun from Old and Middle German?

Comment: The mentioned Germanic "narre". German has "narren", but I would have thought that it is derived from the noun, not vice versa.

Comment: @rha I am not sure where the Germanic root came from but what is clear is that it's not Semitic.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest another possibility, based on the work of Theo Vennemann of the University of Munich as presented by John McWhorter in his book Our Magnificent  Bastard Tongue, that it is a direct borrowing from Phoenician - essentially the same language as Hebrew and Ugaritic.

Compare Ugaritic  (nʿr, “boy, servant boy”)

נַעַר • (ná'ar) m (plural indefinite נְעָרִים‎, feminine counterpart נַעֲרָה‎) [pattern: קֶטֶל]

(biblical) non-infant child
(biblical) boy, physically able young man
(modern) youth, adolescent

Comment: Vennemann ist zwar ein anerkannter Linguist, aber seine Theorien bezüglich semitischer und "atlantischer" Einflüsse auf die germanischen Sprachen haben nur wenig Zustimung erfahren.